# downloading file in PHP

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to create a temporary download link for download files.
my code is:

```
$file_temp_adrs = "temp/".md5(microtime());
mkdir($file_temp_adrs);
$file_temp_adr = $file_temp_adrs."/".$fileinfo['org_filename'];
$file_org_adr = "files/".$fileinfo['filename'];
copy($file_org_adr , $file_temp_adr);

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_temp_adr);
finfo_close($finfo);
$name = basename($file_temp_adr);
$size = filesize($file_temp_adr);


header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Connection: close");
```

When i click on download button, the browser saves a file with true name and extention but the file size is 0KB that is not usable.
where is wrong?

Comment: What is your content length? ($size)

Comment: You need to stream the file out to the user before you close the connection. Try using `fpassthru`.

Comment: @Alexei it depends on file.

Comment: @DomWeldon what is the output type of `fpassthru` and how can i use that?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - is it the expected value or zero?

Comment: @Alexei I tested that with `echo` and it returned true value.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not actually deliver the file content and you should output the file content using [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
readfile($file_temp_adr);
```